# Got lot of ul li list and need to open and close FB comment box on click

Tags: jquery, facebook, performance, toggle, facebook-comments

Site referring to is here.
http://rabbletrends.com/

As of now the comment box is hidden in CSS(display:none;) and toggle with jquery.
But the load time is way too much. My guess is if it just load the page without FB comment box and load the comment box when icon is clicked(toggle).

Is this possible, been searching the FB Developer section but could not find it.

FYI:The ul li list is updated constantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not simply load comments box into an iframe? that should make the page load right away with comments box loading in its own frame

Comment: FB plugin doesn't have iframe for comment box.

Comment: i just visited your site.. it seems pretty normal speed for me, no huge loading time

Comment: you can use jquery to create new elements, suggest the hidden comment boxes are not actually created until button gets clicked, use jquery to create elements on the fly.

Comment: Not really. Look at the browser tab, it's loading for few minutes and IE just freezes until it' fully loaded. Also the comments clean, if more comments are added the load time will be horrendous. but thanks for feedback.

Comment: how do you insert the fb comments bubble/counter?

Comment: <fb:comments-count href="http://your-site.com/#comment1"/></fb:comments-count> will insert counter. Bubble is icon. If this is what you mean

Comment: sorry for the delay -- yes, this is what i mean. you can add these elements in dynamically using jQuery, please see my answer for a simple use case

Comment: if that does not work, let me know and i'll poke at it some more :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to give each `<li>` a unique identifier, such as an id.

`$('#my_li_id').append('<fb:comments-count href="your-site.com/#comment1"/></fb:comments-count>')`

you might need to have this occur onclick, thus:

`$('#my_li_id a').click(function(){
    $('#my_li_id').append('<fb:comments-count href="your-site.com/#comment1"/></fb:comments-count>')
});`